# SwiftUI: update list on appear

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to update the list from view model when the app is starting. But it only updates when items are added or removed. How to fix it??

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications


var center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 0.3) {
            
            List {
                ForEach(0..<vm.list.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    NotificationCellView(
                        index: index,
                        vm: vm)
                }
                .onDelete { vm.del($0) }
            }
            .onAppear{
                vm.getNotifications()
                requestNotification()
            }}}
}
```

View model class. I'am appending the list with UNNotificationRequest elements :

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var list: [UNNotificationRequest] = []
    
    
    func getNotifications() {
        center.getPendingNotificationRequests { requests in
            for request in requests {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.list.append(request)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a quick observation, the original instantiation of your view model should be by `@StateObject`, not `@ObservedObject'. Also, I am not sure I follow what you mean by "it only updates when items are added or removed." `@Published` only fires when `list` changes, so if there are no changes, there is no update.

Comment: from what I can see you start with an empty list. So what are you expecting to see when the app starts?

Comment: `UNNotificationRequest` is a `class` this behavior is by design. You have to call `objectWillChange.send()` int he ViewModel when there is a change.

Comment: Yrb, thank you! It's working! I can't share full code because stack overflow don't allow to do it